# How to implement an Outlook styled scheduler in Xamarin app?

Tags: xamarin, schedule

A Xamarin app that is being developed requires a way of scheduling events. I quite like the look and feel of the scheduler in the Microsoft Outlook app as it has very responsive and intuitive control allowing the user to easily drag and extend their event block over a 24 hour period (see below).

[image]

Does anyone know if this was developed using Xamarin, it being a Microsoft product, and also if they have found any code examples of this being implemented in other projects. I know there are premium Xamarin packages out there like syncfusion that have similar solutions but I am not looking to go down that route.

Thanks

Comment: If a company has enough resources they will always develop in native, and I'm sure Microsoft does. Unfortunately, there really are not many free options for Xamarin regarding to custom components. If you can't pay for Syncfusion I'd recommend using a simpler interface with a `Grid` and Date and Time Pickers, or creating a custom component of yours.

Comment: It's a custom control . Xamarin doesn't have something similar ready.